# How to cancel a print in extended OnBeginPrint method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printdocument

I have created a win form application to print labels and it is working fine. 
The only problem is the content is cut off when it has more content than the label size. I want to show a notification when the content length is greater than the height of the label. A possible place to calculate that is in method OnBeginPrint() where I'm getting all the parameters to calculate the dimensions.
But I didn't find any parameter or property which cancels the print when the condition fails. Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: e.Cancel = true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of events raising before some action begins has `Cancel` property on `*EventArgs` arguments. In this case, it's [PrintEventArgs.Cancel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Sample:

```
void MyPrintDocument_BeginPrint(object sender, PrintEventArgs e) {
   e.Cancel = true; // will cancel printing
}
```